# Browsers are not requesting font file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-face, font-awesome

I'm having a really weird issue with font-awesome.

Long story short: browsers are ignoring 'src' part of @font-face and not making any requests for the actual font.

```
//font-awesome.css excerpt

@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
    src: url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'), url('/Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

- All the software and libraries are of latest stable version.
- No errors in console.
- Font files are perfectly downloadable when requested directly
- Tested in Chrome, FireFox and IE
- Another my project that uses previous major versions of bootstrap and font-awesome works fine

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/c2zUh

Comment: A live example would be great in this case

Comment: is there a request on the network tab, sometimes I have had these sort of issues when the path I have in my CSS is not correct relative to where that css file is, usually I would get a 404 on the network tab

Comment: @OJay that's the problem. No request, no error, nothing. Like src is not there at all.

Comment: Have you added any rules to a .htaccess file? Sometimes requests for fonts through `@font-face` are intercepted by certain rewriting rules.

Comment: Try changing all `url` to `font-url`.

Comment: Woops sorry, I was thinking of Rails for a second then. I'm about to submit a potential solution now, please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Not sure about this one, your syntax seems to be fine, its is identical to what I use and I don't have any problems. Might be a silly question but are you hosting said font files on the same server as the page?, as what is in the fiddle won't work, but I'm assuming that that was just an example

Comment: @OJay yes, same hosting, same web app. strange thing with this fiddle is that there is no request for the font file.

Comment: Is there some other error, or invalid syntax that may be effecting it. Have you tried just separating out the CSS for the font into a separate CSS file, and try a very simple page, like just with the words hello world, nothing else, no other css or anything, and see if you are still getting the same error, also (don't think this will be the issue) but does you page have a DOCTYPE, as sometimes I have seen this sort of strange stuff due to a DOCTYPE

Comment: @OJay no errors, i made a test static html - same problem. Here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7081215/tttt.rar

Comment: Interestingly enough. I downloaded your code. I removed everything except the @font-face from the CSS, loaded the page, no request. Added body{font-family:'FontAwesome';}, and reloaded the page, then was a request. If appears usless you use a style that has that font, then it is not downloaded. Now in your HTML, no class (I'm assuming everything is done with classes as this is the norm) uses the font directly. You need to include the base class and then the icon i.e. <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span> and <i class="fa fa-group"></i>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your HTML is not referencing the base class of the icons (to set the font). You need to include the base class and then the icon i.e.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
```

not

```
<span class="glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
```

and

```
<i class="fa fa-group"></i>
```

not

```
<i class="fa-group"></i>
```

you need the glyphicon and fa classes as well

and as a note, It appears that if you do not use the font in a style rule (the @font-face doesn't count) that is actually applied to an element, it is not requested. So unless an element had a glyphicon or fa class the relevant font files would not be downloaded. I must admit, that's news to me.

Comment: thank you! this was so stupid, i was starting to pull my hair out

Comment: You had me stumped for a while too

Comment: That's not the norm for the bootstrap library (I'm currently using it myself) (or even the jQuery UI library, they use ui-icon) , as per the reference, you need both. But there would be nothing stopping someone from putting in a rule for every glyphicon-* to be font-family: 'Glyphicons', its simple enough

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your site in IIS and going to Properties > HTTP Headers > MIME Types. For each of the following, add a new MIME type:

Extension: .otf

MIME Type: font/otf

-

Extension: .svg

MIME Type: image/svg+xml

-

Extension: .woff

MIME Type: application/x-font-woff

Let me know if this makes a blind bit of difference!

Comment: man... again - font files are perfectly downloadable when requested directly.
I have all the MIME types configured.
Again - browser is NOT making request, it does not even have a chance to fail on MIME types misconfiguration.

Comment: Okay well sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Actually, if you have local font files, this is ALSO required.  If you don't go in and set up the MIME types in IIS, they server will return 404 even when the files exist.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try to embed font in woff format -  right in your .css file in  base64.
It's works perfectly in all browsers, and IE 9+

Also, may be scenario, what this font already installed in your system, and this prevent from download...

Comment: Embed should definitely work. 
With existing/cached font it was a good idea. But when i renamed font in css to something new - still no request from browser.